# How to create one common legend for 4 subplots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, legend, subplot

How can I create one common legend for 4 subplots in MATLAB, like this:

[image]

Comment: Well I just happened to know a solution to that. You can just add the legend to the last subplot and then drag the legend to wherever you want it to be.(The last subplot will adjust its size itself so you don't have to worry about that):| But actually I want to find a MATLAB function (like using "suptitle" to add a common title for subplot) or some MATLAB codes to do that. So if you now find that function please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
hSub = subplot(3,1,1); plot(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
hLegend = legend('hello','i','am','legend');

subplot(3,2,3), plot(10:-1:1); subplot(3,2,4), plot(1:100);
subplot(3,2,5), stem(1:10); subplot(3,2,6), plot(randn(1,100))

set(hLegend, 'position', get(hSub, 'position'));
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this before and its disadvantage is that, the legend made the major subplots smaller