# Change position of legend in octave

Tags: octave, legend, subplot

I want to display a legend below or right of multiple subplots, while keeping the aspect ratio of the subplots. Trying the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704815/how-to-create-one-common-legend-for-4-subplots-in-matlab), I wrote the following code:

```
x = [0:0.1:10];

figure();
for i=1:4
  subplot(3,2,i);
  plot(x, x);
endfor;

hSub = subplot(3,2,5:6); 
plot(0);
hLegend = legend('1');
set(hLegend, 'position', get(hSub, 'position'));
```

which produces: [image: output]

The legend should replace the full plot 5. I couldn't find the property `position` at the [octave documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/legend.html), so it's obviously not working.

Is there a way to change the legends position or another approach for printing the legend next to the subplots?

**edit:**

- Octave version: 4.0.3 GUI
- OS: Opensuse 42.2
- graphics_toolkit: tested with `gnuplot`, `fltk` and `qt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```
x = [0:0.1:10];
figure();
for i=1:4
  subplot(3,2,i);
  plot(x, x);
endfor;

l = legend ("foobar")
hsub = subplot(3,2,5:6);
set (l, "position", get (hsub, "position"))
delete (hsub)
```

which gives

[image: Subplot legend]

Comment: Exactly. Thank you!

This works with `fltk` and `qt` for me. Any idea why it doesn't work for `gnuplot`?

Comment: @Marph: The FLTK and Qt backends both share a big part of the opengl renderer in GNU Octave and they only differ in the viewing part and the HMI